# Google Standard app engine nodejs suddenly stops working on PM2 with error PM2 warn: [pidusage] We couldn't find uptime

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, pm2

I am trying to use Google App Engine (Standard) for our nodejs app(runtime nodejs10) and trying to use PM2 as process manager. We have been able to deploy the app successfully and runs perfectly fine for a few hours, without any issues.

Suddenly after a few hours we are seeing error by PM2 and the app doesn't respond. 
PM2 warn: [pidusage] We couldn't find uptime from /proc/uptime, using os.uptime() value

We are using standard Google App Engine with nodejs10 configuration. We tried printing os platform and version with os library

platform - Linux

version - 4.4 which is linux kernel version I believe

Initially we thought it was because of app engine lifecycle going to a sleep mode and PM2 isn't able to recover from wake up of the instance, but we realised that this happened to us when the server is active as well

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "pm2-runtime --public key --secret key --deep-monitoring start ecosystem.config.js --env production",
    "test": "echo \"Info: no test created yet\"",
    "snyk-protect": "snyk protect",
    "prepare": "npm run snyk-protect"
},
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/logging-bunyan": "^1.2.1",
    "@google-cloud/profiler": "^2.0.2",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.5.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.12",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "^2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "easy-rbac": "^3.1.0",
    "ejs": "~2.6.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.1.1",
    "firebase": "^6.3.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.2.0",
    "helmet": "^3.19.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jsonschema": "^1.2.4",
    "memory-cache": "^0.2.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "node-rest-client": "^3.1.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "pm2": "^3.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "snyk": "^1.195.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  }
```

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: "ChallengeApp",
    script: "./bin/www",
    instances : "2",
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: "local"
    },
    env_development: {
      NODE_ENV: "development",
    },
    env_staging: {
      NODE_ENV: "staging",
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: "production",
    }
  }]
}
```

I am getting 502 Bad Gateway response for requests after a few hours but expect 200 response and seeing an error in log file

> PM2 warn: [pidusage] We couldn't find uptime from /proc/uptime, using
>   os.uptime() value

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar issue with GAE Standard on Node 10

Comment: Any update? Am also facing this